# What does the value of active_defrag_running in REDIS INFO mean?

Tags: redis

On redis_version:4.0.2

Documentation of [redis-cli INFO](https://redis.io/commands/info) says its is a *Flag indicating if active defragmentation is active*. However even after turning it off using `CONFIG SET activedefrag no`. It still shows a value `38`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The actual meaning of the flag is the percentage of CPU taken by active defrag's last cycle.

Active defragmentation is disabled by default, so that value should be 0 forever unless it was enabled at some point. It looks like that after enabling and then disabling it, the last value remains without ever being reset.

That last point, about not being reset, is an issue with Redis - its resolution is included in [pull request #6559](https://github.com/antirez/redis/pull/6559).